# Copying An Office 365 Sharepoint Site To Another Installation

Tags: office-365, backup

Is it possible to take an Office 365 Sharepoint Site from one office installation & copy it to another?

I am looking to set up a demo Sharepoint site on my office 365 setup, which I am then looking at installing on several customers Office 365 setups (different accounts & different domains).

Comment: I've found this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj938033(v=office.15).aspx which works apart from that I cannot Authorise the upload.  Still working on this as most of the support seems to be related to Sharepoint Foundation whereby you have access to the server.

Comment: The above post answered it along with this post: http://blog.ciaops.com/2013/07/using-site-template-with-new-site.html

Basically, you need to save the whole site template (which is in the settings menu).  I was just exporting a single page/sheet, which didn't seem to work as well.

Comment: If you solved the problem stated in your original question, you should make it as an answer and mark this answer as accepted answer to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These answer the question

1 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj938033(v=office.15).aspx

2 - http://blog.ciaops.com/2013/07/using-site-template-with-new-site.html

Please look at my comments for more info.

Comment: Please add the details to your answer here, your answers should not be dependent on external links for the basic outlines of the answer..

Comment: Just to add, from what I have read there is a 50 MB limit on templates.